# How do I get the list of the active login sessions?

Tags: command-line, server, login, session

> Nov  9 17:55:46 swi007 systemd-logind[927]: New session 27 of user
>   swi007.

I want to see the list of active login session in ubuntu server and  would like to close the specific session in my server.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here are few alternatives how to get the list of the current active sessions:

- The command [`who`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/who.1posix.html) - display who is on the system:

  ```bash
    $ who
    spas     pts/1        2017-11-05 21:43 (tmux(1597).%0)
    spas     pts/14       2017-11-09 13:02 (192.168.100.110)
    guest    tty2         2017-11-09 16:15 (:1)
  ```
- The command [`w`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/w.procps.1.html) - displays  information  about the users currently on the machine:

  ```bash
    $ w
     16:16:12 up 3 days, 18:33,  9 users,  load average: 4,33, 2,79, 2,44
    USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
    spas     pts/1    tmux(1597).%0    нд21    3days  3days  3days tmux new-session -d -s my-tmux-session
    spas     pts/14   192.168.100.110  13:02    1.00s  0.29s  0.01s sshd: spas [priv]
    guest    tty2     :1               16:15    3days  1.27s  0.17s /sbin/upstart --user
  ```
- The command [`last` `lastb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/last.1.html) - show a (history) listing of last logged in users. It provides few analytical options as `--until`, `--since`, etc.
- The command [`users`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/users.1.html) - print the usernames of users currently logged-in to the current host. It has really limited usage:

  ```bash
    $ users
    guest spas spas
  ```

---

To kill a specific session you could use `who -u` (or `who -a`) to print a column with the process identificators (PIDs) and then you can use `sudo kill -9 <PID>`:

```bash
$ who -u
spas     pts/1        2017-11-05 21:43  old         1597 (tmux(1597).%0)
spas     pts/14       2017-11-09 13:02   .         31822 (192.168.100.110)
guest    tty2         2017-11-09 16:15  old         2225 (:1)

$ sudo kill -9 2225   # force kill the third session from the above list
```

In addition you could kill all processes of a specific user by the following command:

```bash
sudo pkill -9 -u <username>
```

---

See also:

- [How do I find who is logged-in as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980950/how-do-i-find-who-is-logged-in-as-root/981072#981072)
- [How do I list logged-in users without duplicates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978256/how-do-i-list-logged-in-users-without-duplicates/978265#978265)
- [Linux / UNIX: Kill User Session](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-kill-unix-linux-user-session/)

Comment: how to kill specific session

Comment: @zapoxkrishna, check the update.

Comment: you missed the `last` command which as well list all active sessions :)

Comment: Thank you, @Videonauth! Indeed I've never used this command. I've updated the answer.

Comment: For killing all processes I sorta like the `slay` command, but yours will do. Alas with systemd (and its logind) [the _meaning_ of login session seems to be somewhat different](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-login.html#), so you should probably amend this to mention `loginctl` by now.