# How do I list logged-in users without duplicates?

Tags: command-line, users, who

The `who` command can be used to find logged-in users, but it prints duplicate values if there are multiple shells running. How do I get a list of the currently logged-in users without duplicates?

Comment: It should not print duplicate values unless you open multiple tty and log in. However `who -q` might be what you look for, but not sure, have no way to test on a system hosting multiple simultaneous users.

Comment: who -q prints total number and users. Shall we use sort | uniq?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can pipe the output of `who` to `awk` to print only the first *cell* of each record (row) and then pipe it to the command `sort`, that will sort the values alphabetically and will output only the unique `-u` entries:

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Or we can use only `awk` in [this way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9923/201297):

```
who | awk '!seen[$1]++ {print $1}'
```

A POSIX compliant solution, provided by [@dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert) - where `cut` will use the spaces as delimiter `-d' '` and will print only the first field of each record `-f1`:

```
who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u
```

Thanks to [@DavidFoerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) here is a lot shorter syntax that doesn't lose the information of all the other columns:

```
who | sort -u -k 1,1
```

---

For the same purposes we could use the command `w` with the option `-h` (ignore headers), for example:

```
w -h | awk '!seen[$1]++ {print $1}'
```

We could use also the command `users` combined with the command `rs` (reshape data) with the transpose option `-T` and then again `sort -u`:

```
users | rs -T | sort -u
```

We could use and `who -q` with transposition in the following way - where the command `head -1` will crop only the first line of the output of the previous command:

```
who -q | head -1 | rs -T | sort -u
```

---

See also:

- [How do I find who is logged-in as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980950/how-do-i-find-who-is-logged-in-as-root/981072#981072)
- [How do I get the list of the active login sessions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974718/how-to-see-the-list-of-active-login-session-in-ubunutu-server/974719#974719)

Comment: @dessert: the output of `w` and `who` isn't alphabetically sorted, so I intentionally have used `sort -u` in the first solution. Also the output of `who -q` should be transposed (like as the last example) otherwise the result isn't correct.

Comment: I don't think the section on time comparison is useful. Unless you have *thousands* of users logged in, the startup time for the commands is going to be far greater than the time taken to process and print the output. The section just adds noise to the answer without any benefit.

Comment: @muru, you are right. I've removed the [time comparison](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/978265/11) section from the answer.