# How do I find who is logged-in as root?

Tags: command-line, bash

Recently, I have asked "[How do I list logged-in users?](https://askubuntu.com/q/978256/566421)" The command `who` serves well for this purpose. But how do I find who is logged-in as root? Will the username "root" be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume the *root* account is not enabled (as it is by default), so only `sudo -i` is applicable for a user to become *root*. My suggestion is the following script that uses the commands `who -u` and `pgrep -at <tty parsed from who -u>` to find which `user` on which `tty` have executed the command `sudo -i`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C who -u | while read -a line; do  # Output the whole line: echo "${line[@]}"
        IS_ROOT="$(pgrep -at "${line[1]}" | grep 'sudo -i')"
        [[ ! -z "${IS_ROOT}" ]] && printf '%-7s ( PID %-6s at %s on TTY %-7s) is ROOT: %s %s\n' "${line[0]}" "${line[5]}" "${line[4]}" "${line[1]}" "$IS_ROOT"
done | sed '/grep sudo -i/d' | sort -k13 -k6
```

Explanation:

- `who -u` shows the users logged on with the PIDs of their sessions. Probably `LANG=C` is not mandatory - it is placed to guarantee identical time/date format on machines with different `locale`'s settings.
- The loop `while` will `do` the commands while there is stream on the [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).
- The command `read -a` will read the input stream line by line and will assign these lines as an array to the *"variable"* `$line`. We could output the whole line by a command as: `echo "${line[@]}"`. So `${line[1]}` means the second variable of the array `$line` (the first is `0`). In the current case `${line[1]}` is the [TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty) from the output of `who -u`.
- Here is a simple script that will output a "table" with the relations betwen the array elements and their values:

  ```bsh
  line=( $(LANG=C who -u | head -1) ); for i in {0..6}; do printf '%-11s' "${line[$i]}"; done; echo; for i in {0..6}; do printf '${line[%s]} ' "$i"; done; echo

  guest      tty7       2018-01-03 09:52      old        1847       (:0)
  ${line[0]} ${line[1]} ${line[2]} ${line[3]} ${line[4]} ${line[5]} ${line[6]}
  ```
- The output of the command `pgrep -at "${line[1]}" | grep 'sudo -i'` will be signed as value `$()` to the variable `$IS_ROOT`.
- The command `pgrep -at "TTY"` will output the PIDs of all processes on certain TTY - option `-t` `--terminal`, and the option `-a` `--list-name` will list the PIDs and processes names.
- The expression `[[ ! -z "${IS_ROOT}" ]] &&` could be read in this way: if `[` the variable `"${IS_ROOT}"` is not `!` empty `-z` then `&&` or else `||`.
- The `printf` command is used to format the output (*[reference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)*):

  ```bsh
  printf '%s some text %s` "$var1" "$var2"
  ```
- Finally `sed '/grep sudo -i/d'` will delete the unattended line (that contains our command `grep 'sudo -i'`) from the output of `while` and `sort -k13 -k6` will sort the output by columns 13 and 6.

---

Call the script `find-root`, make it executable (`chmod +x find-root`) and execute it.

Here is a simple output:

```bsh
$ ./find-root
spas    ( PID 14035  at 12:54 on TTY pts/20 ) is ROOT: 23518 sudo -i
spas    ( PID 14035  at 12:36 on TTY pts/4  ) is ROOT: 23589 sudo -i
guest   ( PID 23575  at 15:00 on TTY pts/4  ) is ROOT: 23589 sudo -i
guest   ( PID 24321  at 15:30 on TTY tty1   ) is ROOT: 24386 sudo -i
```

Here is a demonstration (in a `mutt` session) how the script works (*[in its previous version](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/981072/7)*):

[image]

---

Place the script in `/usr/local/bin` to make it available as shell command. To do that, copy and execute the following lines as single command:

```bsh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/find-root && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/find-root
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C who -u | while read -a line; do 
        IS_ROOT="\$(pgrep -at "\${line[1]}" | grep 'sudo -i')"
        [[ ! -z "\${IS_ROOT}" ]] && printf '%-7s ( PID %-6s at %s on TTY %-7s) is ROOT: %s %s\n' "\${line[0]}" "\${line[5]}" "\${line[4]}" "\${line[1]}" "\$IS_ROOT"
done | sed '/grep sudo -i/d' | sort -k13 -k6
EOF
```

Explanation:

- The command `cat << EOF` will output the next lines unless the string `EOF` is encountered. Note the backslashes `\$` that will escape the special character `$` and it will be outputted literally within cat.
- This output will be piped `|` to the stdin of the command `tee` (executed by `sudo`) that will write the file `/usr/local/bin/find-root`.
- If the previous command is successful `&&` the command `suddo chmod +x` will be executed.

---

See also:

- [How do I get the list of the active login sessions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974718/how-to-see-the-list-of-active-login-session-in-ubunutu-server/974719#974719)
- [How do I list logged-in users without duplicates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978256/how-do-i-list-logged-in-users-without-duplicates)
- [Why is it bad to log in as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root)
- [How to enable root login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

Comment: Since you're using bash, you could take advantage of `read -a` to assign to array and avoid using awk for parsing, or just assign tons of variables with `read` . Just suggestion. Nice script

Comment: Thank you for the advice @SergiyKolodyazhnyy! I've rewrote the answer.

Comment: @pa3080 Awesome :)  Looks pretty good

Comment: Note that there are other ways of elevating to root than just "sudo -i" - "sudo bash" and "sudo su -" will also give you a root shell, and I'm not sure if this script will catch it.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, logging into `root` account is disabled, however `sudo` users can still log in as root via `sudo -i`. However, neither `who` and `w` command on Ubuntu will show you being logged in as root:

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
$ who
xieerqi  tty7         2017-11-27 23:39 (:0)
xieerqi  pts/14       2017-11-27 23:39 (:0)
xieerqi  pts/0        2017-11-28 00:25 (:0)
```

Here I am logged in on `pts/14` via `sudo -i`, however my original username is still there.  What can be done, however, is to filter process list to find the shell running on that terminal. Of course that process is going to be running as root.

```
$ ps -u root | awk '$2 ~ /pts/'                                                                
 4170 pts/14   00:00:00 sudo
 4172 pts/14   00:00:00 bash
```

That way, by cross referencing you can figure out who is logged in as root in terminal. Remember, that you also should include `tty` into awk command in case there are root users logged in on `tty`.

Another one, would be to filter `/var/log/auth.log` as suggested already in other answers:

```
awk '/USER=root/' /var/log/auth.log
```

However, this is a log file. It only displays who has logged in or failed to log in, not who's *currently  is* at superuser level.

Comment: Odd thing, if you use `screen` while being `sudo su` and create a couple of windows in it, they will be all logged in `who` and `w` as being `root`instead of username --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz2zs.png

Comment: @videonauth that probably also depends on whether or not terminal registered with `utmp` login database, which screen does. I had problems with `wall` in gnome-terminal because `gnome-terminal ` doesn't register with utmp. Even have a question about it posted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Ubuntu, the SuperUser or Root account is named root but is locked by the system and you cannot login into it. To answer your question, yes, the username would be root although you can not use it without unlocking it.

To unlock it type the following into a terminal:

```
sudo -i
```

Then Set a password for root:

```
sudo passwd root
```

More information on this can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: So who will be able to access it?

Comment: @Anony by using sudo in the terminal or typing sudo su to root the terminal

Comment: @Anony, or by using sudo -i and then sudo passwd root to set the custom password for root.

Answer (score 0):

Type this

> sudo less /var/log/auth.log

from there you can be able to browse all logins including those who access root

Comment: thanks.But its showing : Sorry, user "username" is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/less /var/log/auth.log' as root on "servername".

Comment: make sure the username you have, have root privileges or belong in the sudo group then after that you can be able to view it

Comment: fine.Just on curiosity, what if I am a normal user?

Comment: without any sudo privileges you can't as most of the log files belong to a group that requires superuser privileges, unless of course you modified it not to. However, based on your questions here it is only limited to and asking another one would be adviseable. Choose an answer here which you found one that suits you and ask another question.