# Sudo username is different other than root user

Tags: server, sudo, root

I was trying to perform some root-level action on my Ubuntu server. When I switched to the root user, I found that the username is different. I usually switch to the root user with the following command:

```
sudo su -
```

But the prompt was showing as a different user: `webadm-dev`. I checked on the `/etc/shadow` if anyone tried to add some user and I found nothing. I tried to switch to the root user (after switching back to the logged in user) with the following:

```
sudo su - root
```

It got changed. I exited back and tried to run my usual command again:

```
sudo su -
```

and the username is changed back to the root user. I am not able to understand the behavior of this command and this weird change. Please help!

**EDIT 1:** The behavior of the user change in root prompt was only once and was never seen again.

Comment: No you use `sudo -i` to go to a root prompt ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind what difference would it make by using `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su -`?

Comment: ['sudo su -' vs 'sudo -i' vs 'sudo /bin/bash' - when does it matter which is used, or does it matter at all?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used)

Comment: That link is missing something: sudo -i logs as the user used, not as root.

Comment: Also, how does a prompt for a user changes if the user itself is not present in the `/etc/shadow` file? This happened when I performed the switch to root using the mentioned command

Comment: I have myself never seen happen what you describe sorry. AFAIK sudo su -  should always change to root. Nothing else.

Comment: Hi, beingadityak, whether it is some VPS within Azure or Google cloud or it is a native installation?

Comment: @pa4080 This is a server hosted on Amazon EC2

Comment: In this case, the answer of your inquiry already must exist somewhere in the  Amazon EC2's documentation.

Comment: Also the user `webadm-dev` probably is defined somewhere in your control panel. Unfortunately I haven't any experience with this cloud provider and can't provide further help.

Comment: @pa4080 I found out from the documentation that this user is somewhat related with webadm (something related to WebADM control center). Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Unless this is a **reproducible** condition I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to offer much - right now, we don't even know whether `su` actually changed to a non-root user, or whether it was just an issue with the `PS1` prompt string.

Comment: @steeldriver it doesn't look like this will be **reproducible** at the moment. On that part I will be closing this out. I'll update the thread with an explaination for now. If this happens again, I'll update the description.

Comment: @steeldriver for verifying whether anything was wrong with `PS1`, I checked `whoami` and it showed non-root user in the root prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `sudo su -` is as follows:

- This will open a login shell, so `/etc/profile`, `.profile` and `.bashrc` are loaded and this will take the user to the root's home directory and will use the root's environment.

As discussed in the question's comments, the other approach to use a root shell is to run `sudo -i`. The behavior of `sudo -i` is as follows:

- It is nearly the same as `sudo su -` The `-i` (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.login` will be read and executed by the shell.

The reason `sudo -i` is preferred over `sudo su -` is the command will log as the user used, not as root, enabling easy auditing of the commands (who ran what) in a multi-user environment.

On the other part of the question (why is the prompt showing as a different user) it is unknown for the time being why that behavior was shown in the first place. Since the environment had some other auditing software installed (**WebADM** to be specific) *something* was done by that user. That behavior was not reproducible and was more of an edge case.

Comment: This topic is not directly related to your inquiry, but I think it could be interesting for you: [How do I find who is logged-in as root?](https://askubuntu.com/q/980950/566421)